# How to convert hour:minute (HH:MM) string to 24 hour time format in R

Tags: r

One of the columns in my data frame labelled Time has times in HH:MM minutes but these are in character format like so:

```
Time 
----------
02:14
04:16
01:15
12:30 
13:50
```

I wish to convert the times to 24 hour time format, like so:

```
| Time  | Time_Converted
---------------
| 02:14  | 14:14
| 04:16  | 16:16
| 01:15  | 13:15 
| 12:30  | 12:30
| 13:50  | 13:50
```

I tried the following:

```
h1$Time_Converted <- strftime(h1$Time, format="%H:%M")
```

But this returns date (not required) and time and it is not in the 24 hour fomat:

```
[1] "2021-06-01 02:14:00 AEST"
```

Comment: So how do you know that "02:14" is "14:14" and not "02:14" am? It seems your original times are mixed AM/PM and 24hr. How do you know which ones use which reference system? For example, how'd you interpret a time like "07:45"? Is that "19:45"? Or "7:45" am?

Comment: Good point, I should have clarified. Those that are already there (despite being in character format) such as 12:30 and 13:50 will remain as 12:30 and 13:50. All of the rest should be converted, so 02:14 will be 14:14 and 07:45 will be 19:45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
transform(df, new=paste(as.numeric(substr(Time, 1, 2))%%12+12, substr(Time, 4, 5), sep=":"))
   Time   new
1 02:14 14:14
2 04:16 16:16
3 01:15 13:15
4 12:30 12:30
5 13:50 13:50
```

Using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  separate(Time, c('hr', 'min'), remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(hr = sprintf('%02d', as.numeric(hr) %% 12 + 12)) %>%
  unite(Time_converted, hr, min, sep = ':')
   
   Time Time_converted
1 02:14          14:14
2 04:16          16:16
3 01:15          13:15
4 12:30          12:30
5 13:50          13:50
```

Comment: this works great, thanks! Accepting this as it was the first solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


data.frame(time = c('02:14', '04:16', '01:15', '12:30', '13:50')) %>% 
  mutate(
    time = hm(time),
    time_converted = if_else(time < hours(12), time + hours(12), time))
```